# How to keep PHP from strippng XML tags when echoing a string

Tags: php, xml, php-5.6

I am executing an external command in PHP via exec and I take that output (which is an array) and then get the individual strings search for specific strings.  I then wish to echo those strings to the screen.  However, some of these strings contains XML examples and they are getting stripped.  How can I keep PHP from stripping the XML?  I'm using PHP 5.6.2.

For example, I am trying to echo $val that has the following output:

```
Missing test tag.  Please add the test tag and set it to true.  i.e. <data><test>true</test></data>.
```

But instead I am getting the following:

```
Missing test tag. Please add the test tag and set it to true. i.e. true.
```

As you can see, the "data" and "test" xml tags are getting stripped.

Comment: Right-click.  View page source.  Weep.

Comment: Define "screen". I suspect you mean into a browser window which means it will treat the output as HTML (sorta). In which case @Mureinik answer is one solution - because the tags are interpreted as markup they will not be visible and `htmlentities` will convert them to visible characters. Another option would be to set a different `Content-Type` header (like `text/plain`).

Comment: Or try to execute your script from a command-line like this: `php script.php`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could convert them to [`htmlentities`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php):

```
$str = 'Missing test tag.  Please add the test tag and set it to true.  i.e. <data><test>true</test></data>.';
echo htmlentities($str, ENT_XHTML);
```

Comment: If you edit your answer to explain why they want to use htmlentities, I'll be happy to upvote.

Comment: Worked.  Specifically, I added "echo htmlentities($val, ENT_XML1);"